# Create multiple linear layouts and text views programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

**Create multiple linear layouts and text views programmatically**

**I have tried to explain please see the code of xml file to understand the question**

**See image for my desired output**

**The xml code below is  what I want exactly but programmatically**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABc" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout
```

> I want to achieve the same output but programmatically

[image: desired image output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

add `LinearLayout` into your xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

</LinearLayout>
```

and change in your Java file like this

```
 LinearLayout ll_main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_main);

    for(int i= 0; i <5 ;i++) {
        LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(Main.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        param.weight = 1;
        parent.setLayoutParams(param);
        parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(Main.this);
        tv.setText("T1");

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(Main.this);
        tv2.setText("T2");
        parent.addView(tv);
        parent.addView(tv2);
        ll_main.addView(parent);
    }
```

Comment: dear please see my updated question its much clearer

Comment: yes this is the answer of your updated question @newpie

Comment: its create one linear with two textviews how to create 5 linears and every linear with two textviews?

Comment: check first there are alreaddy five `LinearLayout` and each layout contains two `TextView`

Comment: @newpie `LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(Main.this);` is inside forloop so it contains different five `Layout`

Comment: yeah i just tried code and got output with one linear and 2 textviews  .. i think u never use int=i....  but i have got my desired output  with help of your ans ..thnk u

Comment: @newpie always wc. happy to know that.

Answer (score 0):

**i just got my answer and its below**

```
LinearLayout ll_main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
            ll_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int j = 5;
            final LinearLayout[] linearlayout = new LinearLayout[j];

            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                param.weight = 1;
                parent.setLayoutParams(param);
                parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("T1");

                TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
                tv2.setText("T2");
                parent.addView(tv);
                parent.addView(tv2);
                linearlayout[i] = parent;
                ll_main.addView(parent);

            }

    }
}
```